# Why i am getting null pointer exception for inserting at the end of node?

Tags: java, linked-list

I am solving linked list question on geeksforgeeks platform and i was given a question, i will mention the link to check it. I am getting nullpointer expection for this.
link:- [https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/linked-list-insertion-1587115620/1/?category[]=Linked%20List&difficulty[]=-1&page=1&query=category[]Linked%20Listdifficulty[]-1page1#](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/linked-list-insertion-1587115620/1/?category%5B%5D=Linked%20List&difficulty%5B%5D=-1&page=1&query=category%5B%5DLinked%20Listdifficulty%5B%5D-1page1#)

Code:-

```
 Node insertAtBeginning(Node head, int x)
{
    // code here
    Node inserting = new Node(x);
    inserting.next = head;
    return inserting;
}

// Should insert a node at the end
Node insertAtEnd(Node head, int x)
{
    // code here
    Node first = head;
    while(head.next != null){
        head = head.next;
    }
    Node inserting = new Node(x);
    head.next = inserting;
    return first;
    
}
```

Comment: Please also add the exception stack trace and the main code where you call the insert functions. Maybe you can add a null check for the `head` object. If the `head` is `null` return the created `inserting` object.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the problem description:

> Hint: When inserting at the end, make sure that you handle NULL explicitly.

It seems if the list is not initialized  and the `insertAtEnd` method is called, the 'head' parameter is null. That case is given by example 2 in the problem description.

I suggest to make null like check like:

```
Node insertAtEnd(Node head, int x){
  if(head == null){
    return new Node(x);
  }
  ...
}
```